# Python re library in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex, python-re

I have a Pandas dataframe with rows in a column:

```
55297173-0087-1  
56397873-0186  
57885358-0045-1  
59982876-0016  
62640999-0002  
63025362-0075-2
```

and I need to delete all symbols after the second `-`; if there is no second `-` nothing should change within that row. And finaly I need to get this

```
55297173-0087  
56397873-0186  
57885358-0045  
59982876-0016  
62640999-0002  
63025362-0075
```

and it is dataframe with many columns, but this is what I need for one column.

I tried `split`, but it deletes part of one '-' row, which is wrong:

```py
k = '57885358-0045'
k.split("-", 1)[0]
57885358          # this is not good

s = '58234455-0133-2'
s.rsplit("-", 1)[0]
58234455-0133     # this is good!
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['000-000-11', '000-00', '0000-0000-11', '111-1111-00']})

df['data'] = df['data'].map(lambda id: id if id.count('-') == 1 else id[:id.rindex('-')])
```

Explanation:

```
df['data'] = ...
```

will replace only the desired column;

```
df['data'].map(func)
```

will apply `func` to every element of the `data` column;

```
lambda id: id if id.count('-') == 1 else id[:id.rindex('-')]
```

is equivalent to the function:

```py
def func(id):
    if id.count('-') == 1:
        return id
    else:
        return id[:id.rindex('-')]
```

Finally, `id.rindex('-')` returns the position of the last `-`. Since `id[:pos]` returns all characters from the first to the position `pos` (not including the character at `pos`), `id[:id.rindex('-')]` will return everything before the last `-`.

If you need to generalize to more segments, then a regular expression would be more adequate.

Result:

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 000-000 |
| 1 | 000-00 |
| 2 | 0000-0000 |
| 3 | 111-1111 |

Comment: Thank you very much, will try. And whats mean this row. id[:id.rindex('-')]. ?

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'], 
                   'B': ['55297173-0087-1', '56397873-0186', '57885358-0045-1', '59982876-0016', '62640999-0002', '63025362-0075-2'],
                  },
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You can extract only the part that you want to keep, like this

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract(r'^(\d+-\d+)')
```

matching the pattern of one or more digits, a dash and one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex is faster (str helps here):

```
   df=pd.DataFrame([x.strip() for x in '''55297173-0087-1  
   56397873-0186  
   57885358-0045-1  
   59982876-0016  
   62640999-0002  
   63025362-0075-2'''.splitlines()])
   df[0].str.split('-').str[:2].str.join('-')
   Out[10]: 

0    55297173-0087
1    56397873-0186
2    57885358-0045
3    59982876-0016
4    62640999-0002
5    63025362-0075
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not bent on using the `str.rslpit()` function, here is how you can achieve the same using a [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function and mixing some `udf` or [User Defined Functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-udf-mutation) and its usage to mutate Columns:

```
# Your DataFrame
data = {'Column': [
    '55297173-0087-1',
    '56397873-0186',
    '57885358-0045-1',
    '59982876-0016',
    '62640999-0002',
    '63025362-0075-2'
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Applying a lambda function to modify the column values. 

df['Column'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.split('-')[:2]) if '-' in x else x)

print(df)
```

Here

1. `.apply(...)`: Apply a function to each element in the specified
   column
2. `lambda x:`: Define an anonymous (lambda) function that takes a single argument x.
3. `x.split('-')`: Split the string x into a list using '-' as the delimiter.
4. `[:2]`: Take the first two elements from the list (before the second '-').
5. `'-'.join(...)`: Join the selected elements using '-' as the separator.
6. `if '-' in x else x`: If the original string contains '-', apply the above transformation; otherwise, keep the original string unchanged.